# How can I handle multipart form data in Java NIO Htttp Server

Tags: java, nio, multipartform-data, nonblocking

I have implemented a Non Blocking Htttp Server by using Java NIO. It works fine for x-www-form-urlencoded POST requests. But when i try it for a HTTP multipart request with large file, it is not working. In that situation Server unable to make response to http client. This is my source code for the NIO Server.

```
public class TCPServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       TCPServer server = new TCPServer();
       server.listen();
    }

    public void listen() {

        try {

             Selector selector = Selector.open();

             ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel
                .open();

             InetSocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(8080);

             serverSocketChannel.bind(serverAddress);

             serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

             serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

             while (true) {

                  selector.select();

                  Set<SelectionKey> selectionKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                  Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator =  selectionKeys.iterator();

                  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                      SelectionKey key = iterator.next();

                      if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                          SocketChannel clientSocketChannel =  serverSocketChannel.accept();

                       clientSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

                       clientSocketChannel.register(selector,
                            SelectionKey.OP_READ);

                      } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                           SocketChannel clientSocketChannel = null;
                           try {
                               clientSocketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                               ByteBuffer clientBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

                               StringBuilder requestStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                                int bytesRead = clientSocketChannel
                                .read(clientBuffer); 

                                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                                     clientBuffer.flip();

                                     String result = new String(clientBuffer.array());
                                     requestStringBuilder.append(result);

                                     clientBuffer.compact();

                                     bytesRead = clientSocketChannel.read(clientBuffer);

                                }

                                System.out.println("request-----");
                                System.out
                                  .println(requestStringBuilder.toString());

                                clientSocketChannel.write(ByteBuffer
                                  .wrap("reply from server".getBytes()));

                                clientSocketChannel.register(selector,
                                SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                        clientSocketChannel.close();
                    }

                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    SocketChannel clientSocketChannel = null;
                    try {
                        clientSocketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                        clientSocketChannel.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                        clientSocketChannel.close();
                    }
                }
                iterator.remove();

            }
          }
        }catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

 }
```

Is there any other way to handle HTTP multipart request inside Java NIO non blocking server.How can i fix this. Thanks.

Comment: 'Server unable to make response to http client' is not a problem description.

Comment: I will explain it using the source code. Assuming i send a HTTP multipart request to the server. Request contain a image. According to implementation the HTTP request is printed then server puts a message to the client. Problem is this message is not sent to the client. I think the connection between server and client is down while it processing in the server. I don't know what is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is similar to another question: [Servlet 3.1 - Multipart async processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830391/servlet-3-1-multipart-async-processing), but I'll answer here as the solution works with plain non-blocking IO too.*

Synchronoss Technologies recently open sourced a non-blocking HTTP multipart parser [here](https://github.com/synchronoss/nio-multipart).

As your non-blocking server receives data, you just need to pass the incoming bytes to the `NioMultipartParser`. The parser will make callbacks to your code for each of the parts received.

Disclaimer: I work for Synchronoss Technologies. We wrote this for Servlet 3.1 but it should intentionally work in regular non-blocking applications too, so hopefully others will find this library useful.

Comment: Hi thanks. I think this will works fine with Servlet. But i am not using Servlet for this work. I used Java NIO to implement web server. Could you please explain how can i use synchronoss lib with Java NIO web server. Thanks.

Comment: This parser behaves like an OutputStream. So you can write any number of bytes to it each time, as they arrive. You don't need to supply all the bytes at once. The parser will not block a thread _while it's waiting for bytes to arrive_ (because it doesn't have a thread of its own). However while it's parsing just those bytes, it will use the calling thread to drive its algorithm and make callbacks into your code. Also note there is no dependency on the Servlet API - it's up to your code to supply the bytes from whatever the source is.